# Create different players (Objects) respecting the amount given

Tags: android

I'm starting a new **card game**. It will be very basic, but even though I'm not new to programming, I haven't got much experience on it.

However, this card game should begin asking the user the **amount** of players who'll be playing, and I'm thinking about making a **player** `Class` in order to create players who can have a `Card` (another object) and a `name`.

But when I create objects from a `class`, I have to specify the `object` name, so **how should I do it in this case I don't know how many players (so objects) I will have to create?**

Consider there's:

Player Class

```
public Player {
  private Card mCard;
  private String mName
}
```

**EDIT:**

When we create an `Object`, we give it a `name`:

```
Player objectName = new Player();
```

But there's no way (at least that I know) to create Objects with a different name dynamically.

So, how can I create an object (a Player) if I don't know the name?

**Example:**

If I have 13 players, how do I create 13 objects and STOP. No other Player objects. I said before I could try making something horrible this way:

```
if (playersAmount > 5){
   Player player5 = new Player();
} else if (playersAmount > 6){
   Player player6 = new Player();
} else if (playersAmount > 7){
   Player player7 = new Player();
} [...]
```

But it's really ugly, and I don't really think this is the way it's supposed to be. So **how may I create the exact amount of objects with a different name each one?**

Comment: Use a `List` or `Array` to store the players.

Comment: Already though about that, but then how to get methods from them?

Comment: What do you mean? Try it and post a minimal complete example if you get stuck.

Comment: public Player {private Card mCard; private String mName}   When I ask the user how many players should be created, I later have to create 'em with the default constractor: Player player1 = new Player();   But how can I create the exact amount of players I actually need? (The amount chosen by the user previously)

Comment: I mean, should I create lots of objects with a default name, like Player 1, Player 2 etc ?

Comment: What do you think @cyroxis

Comment: Edit your question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
You don't know how many variables you need
Player p1 = new Player();
Player p2 = new Player();
... // More players
```

An Array is created exactly to solve that issue.

```
int n = // set to number of players
Player[] players = new Player[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  players[i] = new Player();
}
players[0] // 1st player
players[1] // 2nd player
players[2] // 3rd player
players[n - 1] // nth player
```

However arrays have some limitations. The biggest being that you can not change the size. It is typically better to use a List instead of an array.

```
 int  n = //set to number of players
 List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>(); // Array list has an array inside but handles resizing for you.
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    players.add(new Player());
 }

 players.get(0); // 1st player
 players.get(1); // 2nd plyaer
```

Lists or Arrays are also better. Let's say you need to call method `foo()` on every player.

```
 // The old way
 p1.foo();
 p2.foo();
 p3.foo();
 ... // Getting tired of typing yet?

 With a list
 List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
 // Add some players

for (Player player : players) {
    player.foo(); // Call if once for each player
}
```

Comment: Try to understand that I wrote up in the question section ;)

Comment: Try to ask a clear question ;) You have not explained what you are trying to do very well, and shoot down every attempt at help. And have not even really tried to solve it by yourself. I am trying to help you instead of just flagging your question as low quality.

Comment: Try now, from the **EDIT:** part

Comment: You need to create a List or Array of Players, I will update to explain more but that is the answer.

Comment: May I ask why? I mean I'd like to understand why I can't do it that way, and if possible either to know how those players objects will be named, thank you!

Comment: Why? Because 50+ years ago programmers ran into this problem, we need X things but we can only put 1 things in a variable. The solution was to create an Array. Arrays were literally designed to solve your exact problem. Lists are newer better arrays.

Comment: Oh, this is a cool thing. You literally revolutionized my programming experience! Ahahah Thank you so much and have a great day man! :D